# How to serve static files of a service using path-based routing?

Tags: kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress

I've been searching for quite a while on many forums, how to serve static files referenced by HTML pages like `href="/"`, when the frontend service isn't located at the root `/` of my host, using Nginx Ingress.

This question has been asked many times here, but briefly: I have a `example.com/` host, and I need to expose a frontend service in a path like `example.com/front1`. This simply cannot work. The `index.html` returns perfectly, but then a `href="/styles.css"` hits the gateway asking for `example.com/styles.css` instead of `example.com/front1/styles.css`. And nginx just returns a 404.

The only "clean" solution I've found is to manage one subdomain for each frontend service, so it would request something like `front1.example.com/styles.css`. I'm afraid it might not be a great solution.

Some people do [hacks](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54296028) like using `sub filters` annotations to replace `href="/` strings with `href="/front1/` for each file returned by that ingress and stuff like that, but this also falls short with dynamically javascript-generated pages and so on. And of course I can throw all my stuff in a S3 server, but think about it: If I have a cluster of many microfrontends and other third-party self-hosted frontend services (like signoz, which I have no control on the source code), it would be amazing if I could reference every service by its path like `example.com/service-name/` and not worry about anything else.

I've been thinking of a possible solution [in a lost comment](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61757147/6115317) of using `nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/server-snippet` to inject some `njs` logic to replace the base URL by the `Referer` header (`http://example.com/front1`) whenever it references a known service, but I have no idea of how to use `njs`, if it is even possible, let alone if it is a good solution.

Anyway, my question is, has anyone solved that problem and could point me in the right direction? It is for a friend